# Is there a way to see the virtual keyboard presented and how can I close it with AndroidViewClient?

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient, android-virtual-keyboard

After typing a text on some field (automatically with `AndroidViewClient`) the virtual keyboard remains on my device screen.
If I make a dump with the `culebra` script on this step I do not receive views related to this virtual keyboard but I receive views that I currently can't really see since the virtual keyboard hides them.
I wish `AndroidViewClien`t "see"/distinguish the virtual keyboard.
And I need a help how can I close the virtual keyboard with the `AndroidViewClient` (what command should I use?)

**UPD** 
The included `isKeyboardShown()` method checks if Virtual Keyboard is shown, it works!
I wrote the method below.
It acts as a <kbd>BACK</kbd> key event.

```
def back(self):
    self.shell('input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK')
```

That's all I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dismiss the keyboard:

```
def dismissKeyboard(self):
    if self.isKeyboardShown():
        self.device.press('KEYCODE_BACK')
```

Comment: Thank you Diego, but I already found this resolution by myself as you may see in the **UPD** section of the question above ;)

Comment: I noticed. You can answer your question too and accept your own answer so the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: I thought it is stupid to answer my own question. This site also asks me "are you sure ..." when I were trying to answer my own question.  Is it bad practice to leave a question unanswered when the answer appear in the question after **UPD** label?